# How to extract value of a cell using spsheet carate

Tags: rust, spreadsheet

I wanted to extract cell values of spread sheet in rust using "spsheets" crate. Please help me how to do that

```
   extern crate spsheet;
   use spsheet::ods;
   use spsheet::{Book,Sheet,Cell};
   use spsheet::style::Style;
   use std::path::Path;

   fn main() {

    let work_book=ods::read(Path::new("tests/DailyRoutine.ods")).
    unwrap();
    let  sheet= work_book.get_sheet(0);

    println!("Sheet Name: {}", sheet.get_name());
    println!("Number of Rows: {}",   sheet.get_rows().len());

    let cel = sheet.get_cell(0,0);

    for i in 0..sheet.get_rows().len(){
    enter code here
       let cell=  sheet.get_cell(i,0);
        println!("Contnest of Row[{}.{}] {:?} ",i, 0, cell);
     }

   }
```